# The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed

Tags: xml, struts2, dtd

I have written one XML, but in that XMLon very first line I am getting an error

> The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type
>   declaration must be well-formed

below is that XML (space after angular brackets is intentional)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" 
"http://struts.apche.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">  
<struts>

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">       
        <action name="getTutorial" class="org.koushik.javabrains.action.TutorialAction">                
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>

</struts>
```

first line (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`) is throwing the error.

Please let me know why I am hitting this issue.

Comment: Your problem is a simple typo: **change `apche.org` into `apache.org`**. You don't say what program gives you that error. The error seems from Xerces, which indeed throws this error if the referred DTD is invalid. Type that URL in a browser and you see that you get some HTML back, not the DTD, so Xerces is right in complaining about that. Fix the typo and you are all set.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because of the extra spaces between `<` and `?xml` and between  `?` and `>`.

Note that you also seem to have extra spaces at the begin and end of the doctype declaration.

**Edit**

OK, I found two other issues with your file:

1. It seems you forgot the “a” in apache.org in the DTD uri.
2. The DTD available at http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd starts with an XML
   declaration (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`), which is forbidden at the
   beginning of a DTD (because a DTD is *not* an XML file).

If the first error is the one causing the trouble, it will be easy to fix. However, the second error is on the struts developers side. I guess most XML parsers ignores it (otherwise the struts team would have fixed it a long time ago), but if you have an XML parse that do complain about it, I’m afraid your only option is to switch to another one.

Comment: that is becasue i was not able to post my xml here on stack overflow

Comment: just to post my question here i gave that space intentionally , i mentioned in the question also.
Thanks Etienne for looking into it

Comment: Oh ok. I edited the question to remove those spaces. You should start each line of a block of code with four spaces, so that StackOverflow know it’s code and properly displays it.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a dtd it always contains the lines

```
<!DOCTYPE…. [
...
]>
```

Simply remove the first and last line declaring the DTD data, since those are only to be used when having the DTD within your XML file.